# GDI rendering to WPF window

Tags: wpf, gdi, hwnd

I've done some searching, but I can't find an exact answer on this.  In my C# WPF app, I get the HWND pointer and pass it to a C dll.  That C dll then attempts to use GDI calls to render an overlay of sorts on my window.  There are no errors, but nothing appears.  If I switch to a Windows Form, the dll can render over it fine.  If I host a WindowsFormHost control and use the hwnd from there I have the same effect.  I've seen information on the HwndHost control but it doesn't really look like what I want.  Perhaps someone with more knowledge of that control can tell me differently.  I read somewhere that an hwnd used for DirectX rendering (like WPF) can't also use GDI.  Does this make my scenario impossible?  I could fake it by overlaying a borderless form over the WPF window, but obviously that wouldn't be too pretty.  Any thoughts or ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have WPF and GDI rendering to the same hwnd but you can easily have a child hwnd inside of your WPF app and let GDI render into it.  Take a look at HwndHost for doing that.  The section "Hosting a Microsoft Win32 Window in WPF" in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742522.aspx) has a little more details.  It also talks about the various issues you'll run into (like airspace) when doing this type of interop.

Comment: Thanks for responding!  I came across this but it didn't look like what I was looking for.  I don't actually have anything to host.  I just want a "clean" hwnd to hand off to the GDI rendering dll.  Sadly, I also need to be able to hand off mouse up/down to WPF, but that's secondary to the rendering.  Can you give me any guidance?

Comment: You need an HWND and that's what an HwndHost hosts.  Handle WM_PAINT, get a device context and start drawing.